# pseudo code for finding shortest path

Tags: algorithm

we want you to come up with an algorithm (pseudo code) which will be used for selecting the best optimal route among all possible routes from a given source to destination.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching?

There are several good algorithms: Dijkstra's, A*, Bellman–Ford, etc.

See: [Wikipedia - Pathfinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) for more examples (and actual descriptions on the different algorithms).